# Single document, multiple filetypes for download: how to manage?

Tags: 7, entities, files

I want to upload/attach several documents to a book node. Each document will be offered in a number of file formats, for example:

- Report2010.pdf
- Report2010.rtf
- Report2010.doc
- Agreement11.pdf
- Agreement11.rtf
- Agreement11.doc

Given this, in order to:

1. Offer a sensible upload interface (like FileField) that allows an unlimited number of files to be uploaded.
2. Present these files for download, for example:

   - Report 2010 - Download as: [pdf](http://example.com/Report2010.pdf), [rtf](http://example.com/Report2010.rtf), [doc](http://example.com/Report2010.doc)
   - Agreement 11 - Download as: [pdf](http://example.com/Agreement11.pdf), [rtf](http://example.com/Agreement11.rtf), [doc](http://example.com/Agreement11.doc)

**Is there a robust way to relate the different file formats for each document to each other?** By robust, I mean something that (for example) doesn't rely on the user naming the files in a particular way for it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Fieldgroup](http://drupal.org/project/fieldgroup) module seems to do almost everything I need: for each document, I create a group which has a filefield for each file type (PDF, DOC, RTF). It doesn't solve the requirement to allow unlimited files, but the workaround would be to create a number of groups that would reasonably cater for most scenarios.

Comment: Did you use `fieldgroup` or `field_group`?

Answer (score 0):

node-[type].tpl.php

```
$fields = array('field_reports', 'field_agreements'); // you should to create 2 fields for different filenames
$items = array();
foreach($fields AS $field){
  $exts = array();
  foreach($node->{$field} AS $file){
    // delete real extension from file name
    $filename = explode('.', $file['filename']);
    $ext = array_pop($filename);
    $exts[$ext] = l($ext, $file['filepath']);
    $filename = implode('.', $filename);
  }
  ksort($exts);
  $items[] = t('!filename - download as: !links', array('!filename' => $filename, '!links' => implode(', ', $exts)));
}
print theme_item_list($items);
```

Hovewer, this code must be in template.php in phptemplate_preprocess_node function.

Comment: Thanks for the response, however the example file names I gave were only examples. In practice (for my requirements) the files could have any name, and can't be categorised into topics like agreements or reports (there needs to be an unlimited number of documents, each of which need to be offered in an rtf, pdf or doc file format). Sorry if this wasn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

http://drupal.org/project/mimedetect
to ensure the files have the correct mime type, and then

http://drupal.org/project/filefield_paths
http://drupal.org/project/file_aliases
http://drupal.org/project/token

to rename them based on file values

Comment: How does this solve the OP's problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should make a custom CCK formatter (start with filfield_formatter.inc as example) to output the files the way you want without hacking up your template files.